# SQL: Query stored in @query keeps trying to convert to data type INT

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, linqpad, reportbuilder3.0

I don't know why my code is trying to convert the query within the variable to data type `INT`. And what's even stranger is that I got the code working fine on Linqpad. Then I pasted the code into Report Builder 3.0 and tested it again within the query view, which worked fine. Next, I went to report view and ran it once. This worked fine as well. ***However***, once I ran it a second time with a new specified parameter, it threw an error and told me to check on the local machine.

**The code:**

```
DECLARE @item varchar(50)               = '%'
DECLARE @lp varchar(50)                = '1231888'
DECLARE @loc varchar(10)                = '%'
DECLARE @lot varchar(30)               = '%'
DECLARE @trans_type varchar(2)         = '%'
DECLARE @desc varchar(20)              = '%'
DECLARE @whse varchar(4)               = '%'
DECLARE @u_m varchar(20)               = '%'
DECLARE @emp_num varchar(20)           = '%'
DECLARE @ref_num varchar(20)           = '%'
DECLARE @fglot varchar(20)             = '%'
DECLARE @shift varchar(20)             = '%'
DECLARE @truckid varchar(20)           = '%'
DECLARE @trans_date datetime2           = NULL
DECLARE @trans_date_string varchar(10) = CAST(@trans_date AS nvarchar(10))
DECLARE @shiftdate datetime2            = NULL
DECLARE @shiftdate_string varchar(10)  = CAST(@shiftdate AS nvarchar(10))
DECLARE @createdate datetime2           = NULL
DECLARE @createdate_string varchar(19) = CAST(@createdate AS nvarchar(19))
DECLARE @ref_line_suf int               = 4
DECLARE @ref_line_suf_string varchar(2) = CAST(@ref_line_suf AS varchar(2))
DECLARE @qty decimal                    = NULL
DECLARE @qty_string varchar(30)         = CAST(@qty AS varchar(30))

--Define query
DECLARE @query as nvarchar(2500)
SET @query = 

'SELECT TOP (10000)

    *

FROM 

    isw_lptrans AS t 

WHERE

    1=1' 

+ CASE 
    WHEN @item = '%' OR @item = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.item LIKE ' + '''' + @item + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @lp = '%' OR @lp = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.lp_num LIKE ' + '''' + '%' + @lp + '%' + '''' 
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @loc = '%' OR @loc = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.loc = ' + '''' + @loc + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @lot = '%' OR @lot = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.lot = ' + '''' + @lot + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @trans_type = '%' OR @trans_type = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.trans_type = ' + '''' + @trans_type + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @desc = '%' OR @desc = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.description LIKE ' + '''' + '%' + @desc + '%' + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @whse = '%' OR @whse = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.whse = ' + '''' + @whse + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @u_m = '%' OR @u_m = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.u_m = ' + '''' + @u_m + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @emp_num = '%' OR @emp_num = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.emp_num = ' + '''' + @emp_num + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @ref_num = '%' OR @ref_num = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.ref_num = ' + '''' + @ref_num + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @fglot = '%' OR @fglot = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.fglotcode = ' + '''' + @fglot + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @shift = '%' OR @shift = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.uf_shift = ' + '''' + @shift + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @truckid = '%' OR @truckid = ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.uf_truckid = ' + '''' + @truckid + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @trans_date IS NULL
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.trans_date = ' + '''' + @trans_date_string + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @shiftdate IS NULL
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.uf_shift_start_date = ' + '''' + @shiftdate_string + ''''
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @createdate IS NULL
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND (t.createdate BETWEEN ' + '''' + CAST(DATEADD(hh, -24, @createdate) AS varchar(19)) + '''' + ' AND ' + '''' + CAST(DATEADD(hh, 24, @createdate) AS varchar(19)) + '''' + ' ) '
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @ref_line_suf IS NULL
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.ref_line_suf = ' + @ref_line_suf_string
    END

+ CASE
    WHEN @qty IS NULL
    THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND t.qty = ' + @qty_string
    END
;

print @query

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

**Screenshot of error:**

[image]

**Query print-out with the parameters that create a problem (note: this is from Linqpad, where there is no problem. The problem occurs in Report Builder 3.0):**

```
SELECT TOP (10000)

  *

FROM 

  isw_lptrans AS t 

WHERE

  1=1 AND t.lp_num LIKE '%1231888%' AND t.ref_line_suf = 4
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later I would suggest switching to using the CONCAT() function. It looks like it implicitly trying to convert your characters to int because you are using the '+' operator and instead of concatenation it's trying to do mathematical addition.

Comment: One of the variables that you think is a string is in fact an `int`. Since you've not shown us any of the variable definitions, it's impossible to guess which one(s).

Comment: @AnthonyHancock Ohhhhh wow I would have never thought of that haha

Comment: show us print @query as that presumably returns something.

Comment: @AlexK. Print query doesn't work on Report Builder's query view, but I can print the output from Linqpad (where there is no error)

Comment: I would also spend some time looking into ISNULL() and NULLIF(). You could make this code drastically easier to read and code.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock good tips. This just looks messy because It's literally version 1.1 haha

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever added the variable definitions

Comment: probably that "new specified parameter" is an int-type that you are attempting to concatenate to your dynamic sql string.

Comment: ref_line_suf is the int type variable. Try casting it to some sort of char in the declaration.

Comment: @TabAlleman @ Anthony - yes, originally it is of the `int` type, but then to actually use it in the dynamic query I cast this to `varchar` and call it `ref_line_suf_string`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried running in SSMS?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock Unfortunately, I do not have that option as I am a lowly peon at my company :(

Comment: The most they gave me was Report Builder 3.0, Linqpad, and Microsoft Access haha

Comment: Lol, I'll never understand that mentality. A client tool is a client tool, Report Builder is passing the exact same query to the SQL Server that SSMS would. But fair enough.

Comment: Maybe licensing? My guess would be that it costs more money to pay for another license so that another user could use it

Comment: I would recommend looking at this article for a completely different way of tackling this type of catch all query. The performance of this as posted is going to be all over the place and totally inconsistent. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: I'm rewriting the whole query @SeanLange, gonna post that as an answer. SSMS is freeware, there is no licensing cost. People just have this mistaken idea you can break everything with it.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock looks like I don't have `CONCAT()`. Both Linqpad and Report Builder don't recognize this function.

Comment: Do you know what version of SQL Server you are running against? Doesn't matter if your client tool doesn't recognize it, the server will still run it if it's 2012 or later. If not then I'll have to rework my answer a little bit

Comment: So why top 10000 rows? That is an awful lot of data for a report. But you also have no order by so the 10000 rows could be any of them. And really you need to not use select *, only select the columns you are actually using in the report.

Comment: @SeanLange Because without limiting it to 10,000 will return 12,000,000 when the user forgets to enter in a parameter value, i.e. if all values are wildcards the query/report will crash. Version 1.1, so I just haven't put in the `ORDER BY` clause yet. The important thing is to get the right data without errors, which I'm still struggling with. And I need to return all fields with `*` for reasons not relevant on here.

Comment: @SeanLange I read through that link. He offers 2 alternative ways to handling the catch-all query: `RECOMPILE` and dynamically generated SQL string. I am doing the second option :)

Comment: You are sort of doing the second option. You are always adding every criteria which is not exactly the recommendation. But whatever, if you are ok with that is all that matters. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Oh lol come on, technically yes I'm adding an empty string for every criteria lol but that's no big deal....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for 2008 now.

```
DECLARE @item varchar(50)              = '1'
DECLARE @lp varchar(50)                = '1231888'
DECLARE @loc varchar(10)               = '2'
DECLARE @lot varchar(30)               = '3'
DECLARE @trans_type varchar(2)         = '4'
DECLARE @desc varchar(20)              = '5'
DECLARE @whse varchar(4)               = '6'
DECLARE @u_m varchar(20)               = '7'
DECLARE @emp_num varchar(20)           = '8'
DECLARE @ref_num varchar(20)           = '9'
DECLARE @fglot varchar(20)             = '10'
DECLARE @shift varchar(20)             = '11'
DECLARE @truckid varchar(20)           = '12'
DECLARE @trans_date datetime2          = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @shiftdate datetime2           = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @createdate datetime2          = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @ref_line_suf int              = 4
DECLARE @qty decimal(15,5)             = 5.2678

--Define query
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 

'SELECT TOP (10000)
*
FROM isw_lptrans AS t 
WHERE 1=1'
;

 SET @query = 

    @query
    +ISNULL(' AND t.item LIKE '''+CASE WHEN @item IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @item END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.lp LIKE ''%'+CASE WHEN @lp IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @lp END+'%''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.loc = '''+CASE WHEN @loc IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @loc END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.lot = '''+CASE WHEN @lot IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @lot END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.trans_type = '''+CASE WHEN @trans_type IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @trans_type END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.desc LIKE ''%'+CASE WHEN @desc IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @desc END+'%''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.whse = '''+CASE WHEN @whse IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @whse END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.u_m = '''+CASE WHEN @u_m IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @u_m END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.emp_num = '''+CASE WHEN @emp_num IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @emp_num END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.ref_num = '''+CASE WHEN @ref_num IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @ref_num END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.fglot = '''+CASE WHEN @fglot IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @fglot END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.shift = '''+CASE WHEN @shift IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @shift END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.truckid = '''+CASE WHEN @truckid IN ('','%') THEN NULL ELSE @truckid END+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.trans_date = '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@trans_date)+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.uf_shift_start_date = '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@shiftdate)+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.createdate BETWEEN '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),DATEADD(hour,-24,@createdate))+''' AND '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),DATEADD(hour,24,@createdate))+'''','')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.ref_line_suf = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@ref_line_suf),'')
    +ISNULL(' AND t.qty = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),@qty)+'''','')
;

print @query;
```

Comment: Ok I just checked it and it looks like we have SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Okay, I'll have to rewrite it in hieroglyphics to support your ancient technology. Shouldn't take too long ;)

Comment: Hahaha, very nice. Thank you! I appreciate it!!

Comment: Try the changes I just made, I think they should all be 2008 compliant but I don't have any way to test against 2008.

Comment: This throws an error: `VARCHAR is not a recognized built-in function name. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 195)`

Comment: looks like I didn't cleanly replace my code, just a moment.

Comment: Try it again now.

Comment: This worked!!! I'm gonna test some more values just to make sure. What was the problem though? It looks like you're using my method of `+` concatenation still

Comment: I had to go back to the + operator because 2008 doesn't support CONCAT(). I'm not exactly sure where you were having the error, so sometimes I find it easier to just start over then spend a lot of time finding the problem. I actually just now ran your original code in SSMS and it worked without errors so I guess it's something weird inside Report Builder?

Comment: Oh ok. Well I'm really finicky about things so I'll probably stare at both sets of code until I either figure it out or pass out from exhaustion haha thank you!!!

Comment: Hey, I'm going to update my answer but when comparing the outputs I realized I missed a couple where you were appending % to either side of the parameter.

Comment: Ok. I also noticed that it's not working when I specify a value for only the variable `@trans_date`

Comment: I noticed a couple of my comparisons were out of sync with yours. I went back through and updated them. Then I provided a value for every parameter just to make sure it all looked right. Let me know if you find anything else though

Comment: Wait, so this is weird now - I can put in a value for `@trans_date` into the query in query view but when I go to report view and try the same criteria for the same parameter it doesn't work...

Comment: What is the parameter exactly in the report view.

Comment: I used `5/8/2017` both in the query and in the report view for `@trans_date`

Comment: In the query I successfully got results. In the report view it said `An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted).` And there were no results. It also says `Cannot read the next data row for the dataset TransTable. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)`